# Neo4j - Update relation between two nodes if already exist, else CREATE relation with given properties

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I´m stuck with Cypher. I want to update a relation between two existing (unique) nodes if the relation already exists, if theres no relation between these two nodes, I want to create this relation. 
What´s the correct Cypher-Syntax for this case? I´ve already tried this one

```
MATCH (u1:Person {id: "1234"}), (u2:Person {id: "5678"}) MERGE (u1)-[r:KNOWS]->(u2) ON CREATE SET r.duration = 12, r.count = 1 ON MERGE SET r.duration = 12, r.count = r.count + 1 RETURN r
```

resulting with an **Error**:

Invalid input 'E': expected 'a/A' (line 1, column 185 (offset: 184))
"MATCH (u1:Person {id: "1234"}), (u2:Person {id: "5678"}) MERGE (u1)-[r:KNOWS]->(u2) ON CREATE SET r.duration = 12, r.count = 1 ON MERGE SET r.duration = 12, r.count = r.count + 1 RETURN r"

Hope somebody can help me!
Thanks in advance, cheers guys ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply missed `ON MATCH` vs `ON MERGE` (which is what the error is telling you : `Invalid input 'E': expected 'a/A'`)

```
MATCH (u1:Person {id: "1234"}), (u2:Person {id: "5678"}) 
MERGE (u1)-[r:KNOWS]->(u2) 
ON CREATE SET r.duration = 12, r.count = 1 
ON MATCH SET r.duration = 12, r.count = r.count + 1 
RETURN r
```

Comment: Ha! Thanks for your quick and RIGHT answer... true that, I´ll expected a "better" error-message ;)